# Haskell simplify Dependent Type function signature

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

This is an example of dependent type haskell function `dfunc`. Its type depends on the argument value: zero maps to value of `Int` one maps to value of `Integer` and so on as defined in type family below.

So I have function `dfunc` with signature `GADTInt a -> Dt a`
But I want to get rid of this wierd `GADTInt a` encoding of int and implement a function with type signature `Int -> Dt a` I understand that `a` type is to generic for this.., but I try to cheat with `typeclass NTI` and function `ff` without type signature, to let haskell do type inference for me, and get error, as i understand because `ff` implementation inexpressible in a type signature.

Can I do some "magic" here to get rid of `GADTInt a -> Dt a` and replace it with `Int -> ?`

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Main where


data Nat :: * where
    Z :: Nat
    S :: Nat -> Nat


data GADTInt a where
    GADTZero :: GADTInt Z
    GADTOne :: GADTInt (S Z)
    GADTTwo :: GADTInt (S (S Z))   
    GADTThree :: GADTInt (S (S (S Z)))   

type family Dt a where
    Dt 'Z = Int
    Dt ('S 'Z) = Integer
    Dt ('S ('S 'Z)) = Float
    Dt ('S ('S ('S 'Z))) = String

class NTI a where
    toi :: a -> Int

instance NTI (GADTInt a) where
    toi GADTZero = 0 
    toi GADTOne = 1 
    toi GADTTwo = 2
    toi GADTThree = 3

dfunc :: GADTInt a -> Dt a
dfunc GADTZero = 1
dfunc GADTOne = 1000000000000000000000000000000
dfunc GADTTwo = 3.14
dfunc GADTThree = "Hi"

ff i 
     | toi GADTZero == i = dfunc GADTZero     
     | toi GADTOne == i = dfunc GADTOne
     | toi GADTTwo == i = dfunc GADTTwo     
     | toi GADTThree == i = dfunc GADTThree
     | otherwise = undefined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to use a `Dt a` is to know what `a` is. Because types are erased, you will need a run-time representation of it, for example using the `GADTInt` singleton. You can package those in an existential type:

```
data SomeDt where
  SomeDt :: GADTInt a -> Dt a -> SomeDt
```

It's also useful to wrap the singleton in another existential type:

```
data SomeGADTInt where
  SomeGADTInt :: GADTInt a -> SomeGADTInt
```

so that you can define the "non-dependent" tagging:

```
toTag :: Int -> SomeGADTInt
toTag 0 = SomeGADTInt GADTZero
toTag 1 = SomeGADTInt GADTOne
toTag 2 = SomeGADTInt GADTTwo
toTag 3 = SomeGADTInt GADTThree
```

wrap `dfunc`:

```
someDFunc :: SomeGADTInt -> SomeDt
someDFunc (SomeGADTInt i) = SomeDt i (dfunc i)
```

compose:

```
ff :: Int -> SomeDt
ff = someDFunc . toTag
```

Comment: `SomeDt` could also be expressed as `Sigma GADTInt Dt`, using [`Sigma` from `singletons`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-3.0.2/docs/Data-Singletons-Sigma.html#t:Sigma), but in practice, I find that a specialised GADT like this is far easier to work with.